# Ms dynamics Web API 401 Unauthorized

Tags: dynamics-crm, adal

I have a msdynamics crm trail account, I register my Crm in Azure Active Directory as **web app/api** and url as http://localhost and I gave permission for **Dynamic CRM online** as checking the delegate permission.

Below is the code I am using to get the **access_token**

```
private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        /*
         * Replace {client_id} with ApplicationID and {password} with
         * password that were used to create Service Principal above.
         */
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET);

        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://XXXXXXXX.api.crm8.dynamics.com",
                credential, null);
        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I am getting the **access_token** and the code I am using to load leads..

```
 URL url = new URL(RESOURCE + "/api/data/v8.0/opportunities?$select=name,&$expand=parentcontactid($select=contactid,firstname,lastname,jobtitle,company,emailaddress1,telephone1,telephone2)&$filter=statecode%20eq%200");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        connection.addRequestProperty("OData-Version", "4.0");


        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("res code : "+ responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

But I am getting response code **401 Unauthorized**. Can any one please help me?

Comment: WebAPI is really meant to be used from the inside CRM. From the outside you're better off using the Xrm.Tooling.Connector (ex-Xrm.Client)

Comment: But I need to connect it via rest api, I am not supposed to use soap endpoint I resolved this use by assigning role and  adding this AAD client id to the CRM's  application user. But now task is I should not use Azure ClientID and ClientSecret rather to use CRM credentials (username/password) to connect with the CRM. Any help would be Appreciated..